# Is there a way to read/respond to iPhone text messages on a Windows computer?

Tags: iphone, messages, text

I would like to be able to read/respond to my text messages on a computer.  I only seem to find a place to do this if you have a Mac.  Can this be done on a Windows computer or Chromebooks running Chrome OS?

Comment: Would you be willing to sign up for a Google Voice number and tell people to SMS that number instead? You could also have calls to the Google Voice number forwarded to your iPhone and you could get email notifications for all SMS messages you get. Or you can tell people to message you with an IM app instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only use iMessages on iOS and Mac OS devices.

Comment: What if it is SMS and not an imessage?

Comment: If it's an SMS you *might* be able to log onto your cellular provider's site to read them.  Some providers allow users to view SMS messages via the web.  You'd need to contact your cell provider.